# Will 'mouse.bat moveBy 1x1' keep the screen from locking in an RDP session if it's run under a different user?

Tags: batch-file, scheduled-tasks, lock-screen

I'm using [this Mouse.bat batch file](https://github.com/npocmaka/batch.scripts/blob/master/hybrids/.net/c/mouse.bat) to keep my screen from locking after 15 minutes (it's enforced by Group Policy). I have it set as a scheduled task to run every 10 minutes and it works with my logged in user, but it flashes a CMD.exe window on the screen, which I don't like.
I RDP into this machine so I can use both my monitors (I have no docking station ATM).

My questions:

1. Will it keep the session active (the screen from locking) by running
   this as a different local admin?
2. If not, is it possible to set a
   "quiet" switch to keep the CMD.exe window from popping up?

**EDIT**: The answer to #1 is unfortunately a "no."
Anyone know a way to make the mouse.bat file run silently so there's no CMD.exe pop-up? I tried an `/s` switch, but no joy.

Comment: This file is a WIndows batch script and C# source code in one file. The script part will search for the .NET framework and try to compile and run the C# program. You could compile the program manually and try to use the compiled program instead of the script. If this doesn't prevent the console window from popping up, you might have to change the application type from a console application to a Windows application. See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/3571627/10622916 (This question with its answers don't provide a full solution, but only hints.)

Comment: @Bodo above is 100% correct.. but I have had the same problem in the past and I use [this](https://www.zhornsoftware.co.uk/caffeine/) free app.  It runs in the system tray.  I am a programmer.. I could quite easily solve this by compiling code or simple writing an app to keep everything awake.. but I like this app and I don't have to write or compile it.

Comment: Thanks. I cannot use Caffeine anymore because it keeps throwing junk characters in the CLI - the overwhelming majority of my time is spent in the CLI, so that doesn't work for me.

Comment: Do either of you know a way to make the mouse.bat file run silently so there's no CMD.exe pop-up? I tried an /s switch, but no joy.

Comment: @SamAndrew81 Did you try the suggestions in my previous comment? Did you read the referenced question and the anwers? There are two problems: 1. The .bat file runs in a CMD window and compiles the C# program. This can easily be avoided by manually doing the compilation step and running the resulting program instead. 2. The C# program is a console application, so it will probably show a console window itself. According to the information in the referenced question and its answers this cannot be avoided except by converting it to a Windows application. I don't have a detailed solution.

Comment: Thank you, @Bodo. I'm an Ops guy, not a Dev, so I don't know how to compile the .EXE :/

Comment: When you run the `mouse.bat` file, I think it will create a file `mouse.exe` in the current directory, so look for this file and run this directly with the same arguments. I guess it will still show a CMD window, but for a shorter time. If this is not sufficient, you would need a C# developer to implement this as a Windows application. The task might be too big for a question on this site.

Comment: If you can't find a proper solution, `start /min mouse.exe` (or `mouse.bat` - I don't use it so you have to try) might be an acceptable workaround. The `cmd` window will still exist for a short time, but minimized.